# The shortest C program, still causes segfault

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

For a moment I was very proud of myself to have written my probably first C bug-free program.
Here is the entire source code:

```
int main;
```

It compiles perfectly even without the `int`, but a warning is issued (even without `-Wall`) and, as a programmer who is aiming at a bug-free program, I treat them as errors.

Having happily compiled this application, I immediately rushed to launch it. To my surprise, a segmentation fault error appeared...

---

Now seriously. **What is exactly happening?**

My guess is as follows: it's the lack of `main`'s definition. This is so obvious and yet the compiler permits it. OK, `main` may be defined in a different unit. But even the linker doesn't do anything about it. Any particular reason why?

Comment: I think the problem is that you just define the prototype but not the function itself, but wait: You just define a variable and no functions. So far the entry point is not defined.

Comment: This [explanation on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/19xyw1/some_dark_corners_of_c_presentation/c8swcpi?context=2) might help.

Comment: It depends on how and where you compile your program. Hosted environment programs need a `main` but Freestanding environment programs don't.

Comment: Your program is not valid *C* (in hosting environment programs). The standard requires `main` to be a function. You are getting undefined behavior. The linker gets a `main` symbol defined. Then the startup code `crt0.o` is calling that, hence crashing.

Comment: If it's segmentation fault I think (not sure) that it's because lack of return code. You should use GCC to also generate the assembly and see exactly what's going on.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Nopes. Only hosted environment programs need a main.

Comment: @DCoder the reddit thread is actually interesting! Didn't see it before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding warnings: `gcc -Wall -g -o main main.c` gives me  
`main.c:1: warning: ‘main’ is usually a function` (using `gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5`).

Comment: @alk +1, didn't use Wall

Comment: @DCoder you (or the original poster) should probably cite the linked explanation as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The word `main` is a legal name for any variable. The typical use case is to provide a function of the name `main` to a compiler, which compiles it to an object file, which in turn is linked to with `crt0.o` that provides initialization for run-time (stack allocation etc.) and jumps to the label `main`.

In C object files the symbols are not associated with prototypes and the linker succeeds in linking a global variable `int main;` as the main program to be jumped to. This program, however, is garbage. It's most likely initialized as zeros, but soon the processor encounters either a random instruction that accesses memory outside the programs allocated data space (stack + heap), or the instruction flow reaches the limits of the reserved code space.

Both will cause a segmentation fault. And actually, if the system runs on an architecture with *eXecution flags*, the program segfaults at the first attempt to jump to *data* segment or page without execution permission.

Further reading to support the discussion in the comments: [Data Execute Prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention), [NX_bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)

Comment: In MS-DOS era I suppose, it was possible to write a working `char main=0xc3;`

Comment: try `const char main=0xc3;`

Comment: Right, or even `const main=195;`

Comment: On any decent modern OS though, `const char main=0xc3` will probably segfault anyway because the data section of the executable isn't supposed to be executable.

Comment: Works on x64 Ubuntu. The point is that `const` arrays/strings are compiled in .text segment in order of to be reached with `mov label[%rip], %rax` paradigm, which is the shortest machine code sequence in x64 to load a 64-bit constant.

Comment: Fine answer. I only wish it was completed it with some references (e.g. about data execution prevention). Just for the sake of completeness. The reddit thread could be useful.